# clickhouse window function difficulties - hoew to work with date windows

Tags: sql, window-functions, clickhouse

I have web sessions with utm tags (different channels of traffic: cpc, smm, push). Some of them with tags but some sessions from organic without utm tags. I want to overwrite organic sessions to previous tags

Rules, which I want to use:

- push channel remains only for the session in which it is registered
- all other non-empty channels are forwarded to all empty sessions for the current and next day.
- Channels are not overwritten - that is, if at first there was a cpc channel, and then on the same day there was an smm channel, then cpc sessions go first, and then smm for the current and next day.
  clickhouse version 22.8.10.29
  [image: Example what I want to get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Idea use arrays with union all for push channel

```
    select install_id, session_id, date_uz , started_at,  utm_medium, utm_medium_final
from (
    SELECT *, arrayFirst(x -> x!='', arrayReverse(utm_medium_array)) as utm_medium_new,
    maxIf(date_uz, utm_medium_new = utm_medium) OVER (PARTITION BY install_id  ORDER BY started_at  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as last_date,
    if(date_uz - last_date < 2, utm_medium_new, '') utm_medium_final
    --any(utm_medium_new) OVER (PARTITION BY install_id  ORDER BY started_at  ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND  1 PRECEDING ) as h,
    from (
        select install_id, session_id, utm_medium, date_uz , started_at,  
        groupArray(utm_medium) OVER (PARTITION BY install_id  ORDER BY started_at  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS utm_medium_array  
        from marketing.sessions_with_attribution swa 
        where date_uz >=today()-50 
        and utm_medium!='push'
        and install_id  in ('1cc69a1f-eb17-4be6-8bfc-a5dee2dd9c50','57927c21-e862-4729-b38e-f663aa9d227d')
    )
    union ALL 
    select install_id, session_id, utm_medium, date_uz , started_at,  
    [] utm_medium_array,   utm_medium , null, utm_medium
    from marketing.sessions_with_attribution swa 
    where date_uz >=today()-50 
    and utm_medium = 'push'
    and install_id  in ('1cc69a1f-eb17-4be6-8bfc-a5dee2dd9c50','57927c21-e862-4729-b38e-f663aa9d227d')
)
order by install_id, started_at
```